# Ordering of Comment section by multiple columns in MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a comment-section on my site and I want the ordering to be:
1. if user has pinned the comment to the top I want those comment to show first
2. then I want the comments made by the user who wrote the blog
3. then I want the comments made by the user reading the blog
4. and lastly I want the rest of the comments

And I want each section (1-4) to be ordered by:
1. a score based on upvotes/downvotes of their comment and how many answers (= activity on comment) the comment recieved
2. date the comment was posted

So the result should look something like this: (Bob wrote the blog and Alice is reading it)

```
------------------------------------------------
| pin | username | score | date comment posted |
------------------------------------------------
| 1   | Bob      | 2     | 2017-01-25 13:45:01 | // First the pins ordered by Bob, Alice, score, date
------------------------------------------------
| 1   | Bob      | 1     | 2017-06-12 18:42:54 |
------------------------------------------------
| 1   | Alice    | 20    | 2017-03-21 12:51:42 |
------------------------------------------------
| 1   | Jack     | 30    | 2015-02-27 12:58:32 | 
------------------------------------------------
| NULL| Bob      | 11    | 2016-11-21 10:41:35 | // Then Bob's (as writer of blog) comments ordered by score, date
------------------------------------------------
| NULL| Bob      | 11    | 2016-10-30 23:56:01 |
------------------------------------------------
| NULL| Bob      | 9     | 2017-12-24 12:00:00 |
------------------------------------------------
| NULL| Alice    | 30    | 2017-04-21 13:48:05 | // Then Alice's (as reader of blog) comments ordered by score, date
------------------------------------------------
| NULL| Alice    | 30    | 2016-12-01 15:37:12 |
------------------------------------------------
| NULL| Alice    | 7     | 2017-05-21 11:12:11 |
------------------------------------------------
| NULL| Jack     | 93    | 2012-12-21 00:00:00 | // Then all other comments ordered by score, date
------------------------------------------------
| NULL| Jill     | 92    | 2015-04-08 15:45:29 |
------------------------------------------------
| NULL| Andrew   | 92    | 2014-12-31 19:45:12 |
------------------------------------------------
| NULL| Jack     | 32    | 2017-01-12 23:12:57 |
------------------------------------------------
.
.
.
```

But what I get is results ordered by pin/NULL correctly...
But then - as long as pin is first in the ORDER BY - no matter the order of the rest of the ORDER BY (ie. ORDER BY pin, ...) it orders by score, then Bob, then Alice, then date...

So the results from above I get looks like this instead:

```
------------------------------------------------
| pin | username | score | date comment posted |
------------------------------------------------
| 1   | Jack     | 30    | 2015-02-27 12:58:32 | 
------------------------------------------------
| 1   | Alice    | 20    | 2017-03-21 12:51:42 |
------------------------------------------------
| 1   | Bob      | 2     | 2017-01-25 13:45:01 |
------------------------------------------------
| 1   | Bob      | 1     | 2017-06-12 18:42:54 |
------------------------------------------------
| NULL| Jack     | 93    | 2012-12-21 00:00:00 |
------------------------------------------------
| NULL| Jill     | 92    | 2015-04-08 15:45:29 |
------------------------------------------------
| NULL| Andrew   | 92    | 2014-12-31 19:45:12 |
------------------------------------------------
| NULL| Jack     | 32    | 2017-01-12 23:12:57 |
------------------------------------------------
| NULL| Alice    | 30    | 2017-04-21 13:48:05 |
------------------------------------------------
| NULL| Alice    | 30    | 2016-12-01 15:37:12 |
------------------------------------------------
| NULL| Bob      | 11    | 2016-11-21 10:41:35 |
------------------------------------------------
| NULL| Bob      | 11    | 2016-10-30 23:56:01 |
------------------------------------------------
| NULL| Bob      | 9     | 2017-12-24 12:00:00 |
------------------------------------------------
| NULL| Alice    | 7     | 2017-05-21 11:12:11 |
------------------------------------------------
.
.
.
```

**Why is that? and what can I do to fix it?**

Info if you need it:

SELECT-statement (unedited for copy/paste)

```
SELECT comment.id AS commentID , comment.date AS cDate , comment.comment AS cComment , comment.pin AS cPin , comment.randomString AS cRandomString , commentuser.username AS cuUsername , commentuser.randomString AS cuRandomString , ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM commentvote AS commentvote WHERE commentvote.commentID = comment.id AND commentvote.voteUp = 1 ) AS cVoteUp , ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM commentvote AS commentvote2 WHERE commentvote2.commentID = comment.id AND commentvote2.voteDown = 1 ) AS cVoteDown , ( ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM commentvote AS commentvoteup WHERE commentvoteup.commentID = comment.id AND commentvoteup.voteUp = 1 ) - ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM commentvote AS commentvotedown WHERE commentvotedown.commentID = comment.id AND commentvotedown.voteDown = 1 ) + ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comment AS comment2 WHERE comment2.commentID = comment.id ) ) AS score FROM comment AS comment LEFT JOIN userlogininfo AS commentuser ON commentuser.id = comment.userID LEFT JOIN blog AS blog ON blog.randomString = ? INNER JOIN userlogininfo AS viewer ON viewer.randomString = ? INNER JOIN userlogininfo AS author ON author.id = blog.userID WHERE comment.blogID = blog.id AND comment.commentID IS NULL ORDER BY CAST(comment.pin AS UNSIGNED) DESC , CAST(author.id AS UNSIGNED) DESC , CAST(viewer.id AS UNSIGNED) DESC , CAST(score AS UNSIGNED) DESC , CAST(comment.date AS UNSIGNED) DESC
```

SELECT-statement (easy read)

```
SELECT 
    comment.id AS commentID , 
    comment.date AS cDate , 
    comment.comment AS cComment , 
    comment.pin AS cPin , 
    comment.randomString AS cRandomString , 
    commentuser.username AS cuUsername , 
    commentuser.randomString AS cuRandomString , 

    ( 
    SELECT 
        COUNT(*) 
    FROM commentvote 
    AS commentvote 
    WHERE 
        commentvote.commentID = comment.id 
        AND commentvote.voteUp = 1 
    ) 
    AS cVoteUp , 

    ( 
    SELECT 
        COUNT(*) 
    FROM commentvote 
    AS commentvote2 
    WHERE 
        commentvote2.commentID = comment.id 
        AND commentvote2.voteDown = 1 
    ) 
    AS cVoteDown , 

    ( 
        ( 
        SELECT 
            COUNT(*) 
        FROM commentvote 
        AS commentvoteup 
        WHERE 
            commentvoteup.commentID = comment.id 
            AND commentvoteup.voteUp = 1 
        ) 
        - // minus 
        ( 
        SELECT 
            COUNT(*) 
        FROM commentvote 
        AS commentvotedown 
        WHERE 
            commentvotedown.commentID = comment.id 
            AND commentvotedown.voteDown = 1 
        ) 
        + // plus
        ( 
        SELECT 
            COUNT(*) 
        FROM comment 
        AS comment2 
        WHERE 
            comment2.commentID = comment.id 
        ) 
    ) 
    AS score 

FROM comment 
AS comment 

LEFT JOIN 
    userlogininfo 
AS commentuser 
ON 
    commentuser.id = comment.userID 

LEFT JOIN 
    blog 
AS blog 
ON 
    blog.randomString = ? 

INNER JOIN 
    userlogininfo 
AS viewer 
ON 
    viewer.randomString = ? 

INNER JOIN 
    userlogininfo 
AS author 
ON 
    author.id = blog.userID 

WHERE 
    comment.blogID = blog.id 
    AND comment.commentID IS NULL 

ORDER BY 
    CAST(comment.pin AS UNSIGNED) DESC , // first order by pin/not-pin
    CAST(author.id AS UNSIGNED) DESC , // then order each by author/not-author
    CAST(viewer.id AS UNSIGNED) DESC , // then order not-author by viewer/rest
    CAST(score AS UNSIGNED) DESC , // then order pin/author/viewer/rest by score
    CAST(comment.date AS UNSIGNED) DESC // then order pin/author/viewer/rest/score by date
```

userlogininfo-table:

```
--------------------------------
| id | username | randomString |
--------------------------------
| 1  | Bob      | lkjsdf786dsf |
--------------------------------
| 2  | Jack     | 78dsauhkwhe7 |
--------------------------------
| 3  | Jill     | asd78687asyd |
--------------------------------
| 4  | Alice    | ua67asdsd87j |
--------------------------------
| 5  | Andrew   | sadf987dsf7s |
--------------------------------
.
.
.
```

blog-table

```
------------------------------
| id | userID | randomString |
------------------------------
| 1  | 3      | sad86f7s8d67 |
------------------------------
| 2  | 1      | isuydf786iuh |
------------------------------
| 3  | 2      | 876sdfhgwegk |
------------------------------
.
.
.
```

comment-table

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | date | userID | blogID | commentID | pin | ... All info needed ... |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |<date>| 3      |  2     | NULL      | 1   |                         |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2  |<date>| 4      |  1     | 1         | NULL|                         | // is an answer to comment with id 1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.
.
.
```

commentvote-table

```
-----------------------------------------------
| id | userID | commentID | voteUp | voteDown |
-----------------------------------------------
| 1  | 2      | 3         | 1      | NULL     |
-----------------------------------------------
| 2  | 4      | 3         | 1      | NULL     |
-----------------------------------------------
| 3  | 3      | 2         | NULL   | 1        |
-----------------------------------------------
| 4  | 2      | 2         | 1      | NULL     |
-----------------------------------------------
.
.
.
```

Hope somebody can help because I'm stumped... thanks in advance...

Comment: a pin is like a boolean should you not make it 0 or 1 then iso NULL? that might also help you with your ordering...

Comment: Hi, here is a sqlfiddle with your sample data. Unfortunately the query doesn't run, it says `No value specified for parameter 1`, but maybe you can fix it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/baae07/1

Comment: sadly tried it... the results were the same (also it orders fine by pin/not-pin... it is the rest that gets screwed up because scrore takes over the ordering no matter where I place it in the order of the ORDER BY)

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @miknik please post as an answer so this comment-section doesn't turn into a discussion forum... plu just tried all possible ordering of grupy by elements and they gave varying results... but non the right one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ORDER BY pin DESC, FIELD(username, 'alice', 'bob') DESC, score DESC, date DESC
```

You can simply your query by adding an auto generated column to your votecount table which returns the total like this:

```
ALTER TABLE commentvote ADD COLUMN votes int GENERATED ALWAYS AS (voteUp-voteDown)
```

Comment: sorry... score stil messes things up and reorders things... my previous solution that worked was user created pin=3... then 1. update pins written by author (pin!=3) to 2 and pins written by viewer (pin!=3) to 1... then 2. query - ORDER BY pin DESC, score DESC, date DESC... and lastly update pins that were 1 or 2 back to NULL... that ordered the results as I wanted them - comments pinned by the user (pin3) shown first - then comments by author (pin2) - then comments by viewer (pin1) - and lastly the rest ordered by score and if same then date... but thought that was way to much code

Comment: Nope, it outputs exactly like your desired result above [see example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/783c9e/1/0)

Comment: my bad... when I tested it... I couldn't use username as field beacuse the names comes from 2 different left joins - so I switched to userID's for author and viewer since that came from the same source (and does the same thing - ie. identify the user - even better than username)... but in the late hours and my haste I accidentally used id (as in comment.id) instead... still leaving me with wonky results hehe... had a good nights sleep and tested it again (now with userID - duh) and it works perfectly... so thank you and upvote and accepted answer is yours :D